# Bitbucket pipelines and SSH keys: How do I add a new Windows server and troubleshoot connection issues?

Tags: yaml, devops, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

I configured SSH keys to deploy to my Windows server using the following document
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-personal-ssh-keys-on-windows/

I generated the SSH keys on Bitbucket and copied the public key to my Windows server's authorized keys file.
I generated SSH keys on a Windows server and copied the public key to my Bitbucket SSH keys, added my server as a known host, and fetched the fingerprint (I didn't understand what it was used for, though).
My bitbucket-pipelines.yml file looks as follows:
pipelines:
default:
- step:
name: Deployment
script:
- pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.2
variables:
SSH_USER: ''
SERVER: ''
COMMAND: ''

***[This is the error message I see.]
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Received disconnect: Too many authentication failures***

I was expecting to be able to SSH to the Windows server.